# Reduced relative clause that has "NOT"

Tags: negation, reduced-relative-clauses

There are many examples that demonstrate how to reduce relative clause, but I can't find any example that reduces relative clause having "NOT" in it, like:

> I can't find my notebook that contains all my addresses.
>
> I can't find my notebook containing all my addresses.

So, if the original sentence has "NOT", like:

> I can't find my notebook that DOESN'T contain all my addresses.

Is it possible to have a reduced relative clause that has "NOT" in it?

Comment: Without using your example (which I find unidiomatic with a participle), here is an example you can find on the web: ["What did Sherlock Holmes say about a dog not barking?”](https://books.google.com/books?id=aepsBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT180) --*Tight as a Tick* by Toni L. P. Kelner.

Answer (score 4):

## Short answer:

Yes:

> I can't find my notebook ***not containing** all my addresses*.

## Longer answer:

There are three types of reduced relative clauses, [this eminent source](http://www.cambridge.org/grammarandbeyond/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Grammar-and-Beyond-3-Unit-23.pdf) says:

- [Participle phrase](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/participle_phrases.htm)
- [Prepositional phrase](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/prepositionalphrase.htm)
- [Appositive](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/appositive_apposition.htm)

The relative clause in your sentence can be rephrased into a participle phrase.

> Other elements, such as noun phrases, adjectives, adverbs, infinitive and participial phrases, etc., can be negated by placing the word not before them: not the right answer, not interesting, not to enter, not noticing the train, etc. - [Negation, English grammar - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_grammar#Negation)

Thus, to negate the participle phrase, you need to add *not* before *containing all my addresses*:

> I can't find my notebook ***not containing** all my addresses*.

### Other such examples:

> Count the ties *that are not in red*.
> → Count the ties ***not in red***.

> The only person *who doesn't realize how bad the situation is* is you.
> → The only person ***not realizing how bad the situation is*** is you.

### Study more:

[http://www.csun.edu/~bashforth/305_PDF/305_PDF_Grammar/ParticiplePhrasesAsReducedARelatives.pdf](http://www.csun.edu/%7Ebashforth/305_PDF/305_PDF_Grammar/ParticiplePhrasesAsReducedARelatives.pdf)

http://www.eslgold.com/grammar/reduced_relative_clauses.html

http://www.doko.vn/tai-lieu/chuyen-de-relative-clause-1841148

http://www.grammarbank.com/reduced-relative-clauses.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause

http://esl.about.com/od/grammarstructures/a/Reduced-Relative-Clauses.htm

Comment: This is a good answer, but the OP's sentence was extremely unlikely.  You might have gotten more votes if it was based on "I looked for a notebook that doesn't contain any addresses."