# on using "that" to refer to object

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, articles, connected-speech

I need to understand: is using "that" optional or obligatory or should it not be used in this context? Which sentence is correct?:

> We use the terms we defined in [1]

Or,

> We use the terms that we defined in [1]

Comment: duplicate? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67891/reduced-relative-clause-that-has-not

Comment: does this mean, the short answer: both can be correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Omission of “that” (in this text)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56579/omission-of-that-in-this-text) Also [Can “THAT” be omitted here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/145893/can-that-be-omitted-here) and probably others.

Comment: Either version can be used here. It's entirely up to you.